# automatically align properties and in-buffer settings

Tags: org-mode

How is automatic alignment of properties, in-buffer settings and similar things enabled?

I always end up with something like this and then have to align manually.

```
#+STARTUP: indent
#+PRIORITIES: A C B
#+COLUMNS: %ITEM %foo %bar

* section
  :PROPERTIES: 
  :foo: foo
  :barbaz: barbaz
  :END:
```

However I found some signs alignment should happen automatically. E.g. there is this:

```
(defcustom org-property-format "%-10s %s"
  "How property key/value pairs should be formatted by `indent-line'.
When `indent-line' hits a property definition, it will format the line
according to this format, mainly to make sure that the values are
lined-up with respect to each other."
  :group 'org-properties
  :type 'string)
```

Is there a command that will fixup a property to respect that? Shouldn't a property inserted with `org-set-property` follow that format? `M-x org-indent-line` doesn't do anything for me and `indent-line` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org-indent-line` did not do the right thing when the property keyword was right at the beginning of the line.  It does now.

Also, from a fresh git pull, using <kbd>C-M-\</kbd> on the region will indent the region.

To format the options header you can select the region you want to align and do

`M-x align-regexp RET <space> RET`